# How to observe other application icon in OS X?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I need to know current shown icon of another running application, I have tried this code:

```
var icon = NSRunningApplication.runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier("some.app.dentifier").first?.icon
```

but this returns a fixed app icon and if the other app changed its icon this code still returns same icon before change.

Is there a way to return current shown icon of another app or icon identifier ?

Comment: could the code [in this repo](https://github.com/kcrawford/dockutil) possibly help you out?

Answer (score 1):

First add this to applicationDidFinishLaunching

```
let appChanged = Notification.Name("NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification")
  NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.appChanged), name: appChanged, object: nil)
```

Then this function will get you the image

```
@objc func appChanged(notification:NSNotification){
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo![NSWorkspace.applicationUserInfoKey] as? NSRunningApplication {
      let icon = userInfo.icon
    }
  }
```